# How can i adjust the LabelText Height?

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, mobile

I am trying to get the latbeltext "Email" higher so that it can be over the the border

```
 TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: AppColors.pink,

                      fontSize: 24,
                       height: -0.05, // this height is not changing the position of the text 
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                    floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: AppColors.black,
                      height: -0.05,
                      fontSize: 24, // Adjust the font size as desired
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 24.0),
                  
                  

                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: AppColors.darkgrey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    //  isDense: true,

                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Foulen@domaine.com',
                    labelText: "Email",
                  ),
                  
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _email = value!;
                  },
                ),
```

the problem is that the height is only working when the textformfield is focused [when textfield is focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxXv9.png) [when textfield is not focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLNIv.png) i want the label 'Email' to remain on top of the border even when the field is not focused

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `TextFormField` like so:

```
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: 'Email',
      floatingLabelBehavior:FloatingLabelBehavior.always, 
    ),
  )
```

Comment: i am already doing that